# Web.API MapHttpRoute parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having problems with my Web.API routing.  I have the following two routes:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MethodOne",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{type}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, type = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MethodTwo",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{directory}/{report}",
    defaults: new { directory = RouteParameter.Optional, report = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And in my controller these two methods:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("methodone")]
public string MethodOne(string id, string type)
{
    return string.Empty;
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("methodtwo")]
public string MethodTwo(string directory, string report)
{
    return string.Empty;
}
```

These two seemingly cannot live side by side. If I comment out the MethodOne route in WebApiConfig, the MethodTwo route works. Commenting MethodTwo route allows MethodOne to work. Leaving both uncommented, MethodOne works, but not MethodTwo.

I was hoping to use one route for both of these then it seems they would have to have the same parameter names. Who writes methods with generic parameter names? Bad. I really don't want my methods to have the same parameter names (like p1, p2, p3), so I thought I could create a route just for the new method. But even this doesn't seem to work.

I really miss the `WebGet(UriTemplate="")` from WCF rest.

I have one controller that has many methods, some with 1, 2, 3 or even more parameters. I can't believe I cant use meaningful parameter names with the MapHttpRoute approach.

I could comment that stuff out entirely and use `WebGet()` … but before I got there I wanted to see if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this problem is because your first route will match both requests. The id and type token in the URL will match both requests because when the route is being run, it will try parse the URL and match each segment against your URL.

So your first route will happily match both requests as follows.

```
~/methodone/1/mytype => action = methodone, id = 1, and type = mytype
~/methodtwo/directory/report => action = methodtwo, id = directory, and type = report
```

To work around this, you should use route like

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MethodOne",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/methodone/{id}/{type}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, type = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "MethodTwo",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/methodtwo/{directory}/{report}",
    defaults: new { directory = RouteParameter.Optional, report = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Even if you use WebGet, you might need to do something similarly to disambiguous those two methods I believe.

Comment: I will give this a go and let you know if it works.  The bummer is that I need to do this now for every method that I want to have correctly named parameters for.  It might be easier to go the route Youssef linked or WebGet- those are even less work and more clear.

Comment: So this does work- thanks.  However, this, IMHO, is crap.  Not your solution but the whole route approach.  I either have to have a route for every method, which isn't nice, or use the old WebGet or the new GET from the attribute- and comment out all of the routing stuff.  I confess I'm not a huge web guy, so maybe I'm doing something non-standard, but this seems like an extremely limited approach compared to the UriTemplate.

Comment: I hear you. The routing we supported for Web API v1 works well for HTTP Verb based routing only or action based routing only. However, it does not work very well if you have one action with both HTTP verb based and action based, for We are working on improving that story in the next release.

Comment: I hear you. The routing we supported for Web API v1 works well for HTTP Verb based routing or action based routing respectively. However, it does not work everywell, for We are working on improving the story, see http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/184

Answer (score 6):

From http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

> You can also provide constraints, which restrict how a URI segment can
>   match a placeholder:
>
> > constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }   // Only matches if "id" is one or
> >     more digits.

Adding this constraint to "MethodOne" (api/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{type}) would mean that numbers it only matches if {id} is a number otherwise it would match "MethodTwo" ("api/{controller}/{action}/{directory}/{report}").

Answer (score 4):

You can choose to pass the parameters in the query string like /MethodTwo?directory=a&report=b, but if you'd rather they show up in the path, this looks like a good candidate for attribute-based routing. Filip has a great post about it here:

http://www.strathweb.com/2012/05/attribute-based-routing-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: I did try this... seems to be okay, it's just a bit frustrating going from the UriTemplate in WCF to something that doesn't work so hot, and then having to use a separate package. :P I can also use the old WebGet stuff, but then I have to explicitly map the entire route for every method.  I was hoping for the new system to be a bit more flexible.