# custom method with same signature web api mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Web Api with ASP.NET MVC4. For Custom Get methods I am having problem, which I am explaining below.

**my WebApiConfig.cs file is**

```
   public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //1
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //2
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "FindDetailsByAge",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{age}",
        defaults: new { age = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { age = @"^[0-9]+$" }
        );


        //3
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FindDetailsByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
         );

        //4
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FindDetailsByCountry",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{country}",
            defaults: new { country = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { country = @"^[a-z]+$" }
         );


        // for json
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

    }
```

**Here is my controller file**

```
public class ContactController : ApiController
{
    private ContactRepository contactRepository;

    public ContactController()
    {
        this.contactRepository = new ContactRepository();

    }

    public IEnumerable<Contact> GetAllContact()
    {
        return contactRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public Contact GetNameByAge(int id)
    {
        Contact contact = contactRepository.GetNameByAge(id);
        if (contact == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return contact;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public Contact FindDetailsByAge(int age)
    {
        Contact contact = contactRepository.FindDetailsByAge(age);
        if (contact == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return contact;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Contact> FindDetailsByName(string name)
    {
        IEnumerable<Contact> lstContactName = contactRepository.FindDetailsByName(name);
        if (lstContactName == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return lstContactName;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Contact> FindDetailsByCountry(string country)
    {
        IEnumerable<Contact> lstContactCountry = contactRepository.FindDetailsByCountry(country);
        if (lstContactCountry == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return lstContactCountry;
    }


}
```

**When I am executing these methods my results are.**
( I am entering the url in the firefox browser)

case - 1

**input** :

> ../api/contact/

**output** :

> [{"Name":"Ashok","Age":60,"Country":"India"},{"Name":"Nargis","Age":30,"Country":"India"},{"Name":"Nargis","Age":35,"Country":"Iran"},{"Name":"Steve","Age":50,"Country":"South
>   Africa"}]

case - 2

**input** :

> ../api/contact/FindDetailsByAge/50

**output** :

> {"Name":"Steve","Age":50,"Country":"South Africa"}

case - 3

**input :**

> ../api/contact/FindDetailsByName/nargis

**output :**

```
[{"Name":"Nargis","Age":30,"Country":"India"},{"Name":"Nargis","Age":35,"Country":"Iran"}]
```

case -4

**input** : `../api/contact/FindDetailsByCountry/india`

**output** :

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   '../api/contact/FindDetailsByCountry/india'.","MessageDetail":"No
>   action was found on the controller 'Contact' that matches the
>   request."}

From the above outputs you see that for case-4, it gives error.

**FindDetailsByName** is being executed
**FindDetailsByCountry** is not being executed

Now if I place the MapHttpRoute (4th case) before MapHttpRoute(3rd case) i.e. interchange the 3rd and 4th position, WebApiConfig.cs look like

...
...

```
        //4
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FindDetailsByCountry",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{country}",
            defaults: new { country = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { country = @"^[a-z]+$" }
         );


        //3
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "FindDetailsByName",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
         );
```

then output would be

**input** :

> ../api/contact/FindDetailsByCountry/india

**output** :

> [{"Name":"Ashok","Age":60,"Country":"India"},{"Name":"Nargis","Age":30,"Country":"India"}]

**input** :

> ../api/contact/FindDetailsByName/nargis

**output** :

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   '../api/contact/FindDetailsByName/nargis'.","MessageDetail":"No action
>   was found on the controller 'Contact' that matches the request."}

Now
**FindDetailsByName** is not being executed
**FindDetailsByCountry** is being executed

From the above code it is clear that in the config file for routing between 3 and 4, which one comes first is being executed.

I have

**method -1**

```
public Contact  FindDetailsByName(string name)
```

**method -2**

```
public Contact FindDetailsByCountry(string country)
```

You see both the method **FindDetailsByName** and **FindDetailsByCountry** is taking only string parameter and returning Contact object.

Now my **question** is -  How will I execute both the method ? What will be MapHttpRoute ? What will  be MapHttpRoute's order ? 
I have been searching the solution for last two days, but did not get any. I know I have given long description of the code, please read it patiently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need to have a single mapping that covers both.  The `api/{controller}/{action}/` covers the "api/contact/FindDetailsByName/" and "api/contact/FindDetailsByCountry".

With your current setup, the country one would take effect first, and the name one would be skipped because they have the same signature (controller/action/parameter).

Change your methods to accept a generic variable name, such as `public IEnumerable<Contact> FindDetailsByName(string searchValue)` and use a single route for both:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "FindDetailsBySearchValue",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{searchValue}",
        defaults: new { searchValue = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { searchValue = @"^[a-z]+$" }
     );
```

OR don't use templates on the action, as in this answer: [Web.API MapHttpRoute parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764177/web-api-maphttproute-parameters)

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "FindDetailsByCountry",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/FindDetailsByCountry/{country}",
        defaults: new { country = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { country = @"^[a-z]+$" }
     );


    //3
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "FindDetailsByName",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/FindDetailsByName/{name}",
        defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { name = @"^[a-z]+$" }
     );
```